# Spring Data Query with Specifications prevent multiple joins on AND

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In our Spring-Boot-Data Project, we use Specifications to Filter the requested Data. This leads to unexpected results when restricting on multiple properties on the same sub-entity. A Demo Project is available on [on github](https://github.com/kaihenkel/spring-data-specification-problem)

#### 2023-10-20: reworked problem description.

The Actual Setup is far more complicated, but I was able to reduce it to the following Problem.

### Problem

I have two Entities with a one-to-many relationship (parent 1-* child). I want to query the Parent Entity based on two properties of the children (foo and baa) using Specifications. The search properties can be empty, in which case they should be ignored.

This works well if there is only one matching entity in the relationship, but incorrect results when I have more than one relationship where only one property matches.

#### Example

The parent entity has only a name and the child entity has two properties foo and baa.
The following listing shows the parent/children entities

- a

  - true, false
  - false, true
- b

  - false, false
- c
  -- true, true

The query with true/true should return only entity c - but a and c are returned.

### Entities (getter/setter c'tor and ID are omitted)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
public class ParentEntity {
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
  private List<ChildEntity> children;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="child")
public class ChildEntity {
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", nullable = false)
  private ParentEntity parent;

  private boolean foo;
  private boolean baa;
}
```

Listing/Filtering is done via JpaSpecificationExecutor with two different Specifications that are combined with **and**.

```
public static Specification<ParentEntity> empty() {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> null;
}
public static Specification<ParentEntity> byFoo(Boolean foo) {
    if(foo == null) {
        return empty();
    }
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(
            root.join(ParentEntity_.CHILDREN, JoinType.INNER).get(ChildEntity_.FOO),
            foo
    );
}

public static Specification<ParentEntity> byBaa(Boolean baa) {
    if (baa == null) {
        return empty();
    }
    return  (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(
            root.join(ParentEntity_.CHILDREN, JoinType.INNER).get(ChildEntity_.BAA),
            baa
    );
}
```

Listing (Uses Repository implementing JpaSpecificationExecutor

```
List<ParentEntity> list(Boolean foo, Boolean baa) {
  Specification<ParentEntity> filter = byFoo(foo).and(byBaa(baa));
  return repository.findAll(filter);
}
```

### Problem

The created query joins the child table twice, once per property.

```
select p1_0.id,p1_0.name from parent p1_0 
  join child c1_0 on p1_0.id=c1_0.parent_id 
  join child c2_0 on p1_0.id=c2_0.parent_id 
where c1_0.foo=? and c2_0.baa=?
```

When searching for foo=true and baa=true the expected result from the example above would be c, the actual result is a and c, since c1_0 is matched and c2_0 is also matched - but c1_0 is not equal to c2_0.

### Found Workaround: One Specification Call - Works but does not scale

```
    public static Specification<ParentEntity> combined(Boolean foo, Boolean baa) {
    if (foo == null && baa == null) {
        return empty();
    }

    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Join<Object, Object> join = root.join(ParentEntity_.CHILDREN, JoinType.INNER);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        if (foo != null) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(ChildEntity_.FOO),foo));
        }
        if (baa != null) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get(ChildEntity_.BAA),baa));
        }
        return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
    };
}
```

One possible optimization would be to create a Specification-Builder-Like Object that encapsulates the Filter-Options and Joins - still not what I was looking for but a bit more scalable.

---

Additional Solution, based on Andrey B. Panfilov answer, is to use a FromSpecification Functional Interface that mimics the Spring Specification Interface.

```
public interface FromSpecification<T,X> extends Serializable {
  long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Nullable
  Predicate toPredicate(From<?,?> from, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder);

  default FromSpecification<T,X> and(@Nullable FromSpecification<T, ? super X> other) {
      if (other == null) {
          return this;
      }
      return (from, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.and(
            toPredicate(from, query, criteriaBuilder), other.toPredicate(from, query, criteriaBuilder)
      );
  }

  default FromSpecification<T,X> or(@Nullable FromSpecification<T,? super X> other) {
      if (other == null) {
          return this;
      }
      return (from, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.or(
            toPredicate(from, query, criteriaBuilder), other.toPredicate(from, query, criteriaBuilder)
      );
  }

  default Specification<T> asSpecification() {
      return this::toPredicate;
  }
}
```

Which then can be used

```
 public static FromSpecification<ParentEntity, ChildEntity> fromChildByFoo(Boolean foo) {
    if (foo == null) {
        return (from, query, criteriaBuilder) -> null;
    }
    return (from, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(from.get(ChildEntity_.FOO), foo);
}
public static FromSpecification<ParentEntity, ChildEntity> fromChildByBaa(Boolean baa) {
    if (baa == null) {
        return (from, query, criteriaBuilder) -> null;
    }
    return (from, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.equal(from.get(ChildEntity_.BAA), baa);
}

Specification<ParentEntity> byFrom(Boolean foo, Boolean baa) {
    if (foo == null && baa == null) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> null;
    }
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> fromChildByFoo(foo).and(fromChildByBaa(baa))
            .toPredicate(root.join(ParentEntity_.CHILDREN), query, criteriaBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is known disadvantage for `spring-data-jpa` implementation, I do believe the following might be helpful:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FSpecification<X> extends Serializable {

    Predicate toPredicate(From<?, ? extends X> from, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb);


    default FSpecification<X> not() {
        return (from, cq, cb) -> cb.not(toPredicate(from, cq, cb));
    }

    default FSpecification<X> and(@Nullable FSpecification<? super X> other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return this;
        }
        return (path, cq, cb) -> cb.and(toPredicate(path, cq, cb), other.toPredicate(path, cq, cb));
    }

    default FSpecification<X> or(@Nullable FSpecification<? super X> other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return this;
        }
        return (path, cq, cb) -> cb.or(toPredicate(path, cq, cb), other.toPredicate(path, cq, cb));
    }

    default Specification<X> asSpring() {
        return this::toPredicate;
    }

}
```

```java
public static Specification<TopLevelEntity> byFirstSpec(FSpecification<SubEntity> fspec) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        return fspec.toPredicate(root.join(TopLevelEntity_.subs), query, criteriaBuilder);
    };
}
```

Comment: I like your solution - defining a FromSpecification interface that allows me to define my filter-criteria in its ow functional interfaces and combine them as needed.
I will add a solution to my example program